# Pandas: Count Occurrences of 2 Visits in 4 Days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, that looks like this:

```
user_id, date_of_visit
1,        1/5/12
1,        1/6/12
2,        1/6/12
2,        1/11/12
2,        1/27/12
```

I'm trying to find `user_id`s where the user has visited on two different days within a 4-day window.  So the correct output on the above would just be `[1]`.

From a related question, I have:

```
df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x : x.set_index('date_of_visit').rolling('4d').count().gt(1).any()).user_id.unique()
```

The problem with the above code is that it doesn't address the possibility that a user visited more than once on the same day.  So if I had:

```
user_id, date_of_visit
1,        1/5/12
1,        1/5/12
```

The above code would output `[1]` because user 1 visited twice in a four-day window.  However, I want only users who visited on two different days within a 4-day window.  So user 1 *shouldn't* be included in the output.

Any idea how to modify to enforce this constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to drop duplicates based on `user_id` and `date_of_visit` before running the code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'date_of_visit']).groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x : x.set_index('date_of_visit').rolling('4d').count().gt(1).any()).user_id.unique()
```